# Splitting by word boundaries including apostrophes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split each word of a string including spaces and punctuations in different groups, but I want to keep words with apostrophes together.

For example:

```
Phrase: This is right.
Groups: [This] [ ] [is] [ ] [right] [.]

Phrase: This isn't right.
Groups: [This] [ ] [isn't] [ ] [right] [.]

Phrase: "I said ok."
Groups: ["] [I] [ ] [said] [ ] [ok] [.] ["]
```

I'm using the regular expression: `str.split(/(?=[.,"\s]|\b)/)`

However, this doesn't work with apostrophes. For the phase: *This isn't right.* , it's splitting like:

```
[This] [ ] [isn] ['] [t] [ ] [right] [.]
```

Is there a way to keep the *isn't* in a single group?

Answer (score 1):

You may try finding all regex matches on the pattern `[A-Za-z']+|[^A-Za-z']`, which matches either a word (letters or apostrophe), or a single non word character.

```js
var regex = /[A-Za-z']+|[^A-Za-z']/g;
var input = "\"This isn't right.\"";
var m;
var matches = [];

var i = 0;
do {
    m = regex.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        matches[i] = m[0];
        ++i;
    }
} while (m);

console.log(matches);
```

Note that using a direct regex find all approach is sometimes preferable to a more complicated regex splitting logic.

Comment: The OP said "words" not "English words".

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `.match` instead: match a word character followed by (word characters or apostrophes) (`\w[\w']*`), or match spaces: `+`, or match other punctuation (`[.,"]`):

```
\w[\w']*| +|[.,"]
```

https://regex101.com/r/B755JA/1

```js
const inputs = `This is right.
This isn't right.
"I said ok."`.split('\n');
for (const input of inputs) {
  console.log(input.match(/\w[\w']*| +|[.,"]/g));
}
```